# Expert system Basics

Tags: expert-system

I need do write an expert systems that should aid user in picking up best mobile phone operator. It should be very simple and not based on languages/libaries such as CLISP or JESS. So I need to write it all from the ground up.

Do you know some books or online tutorials that explains how this can be done?
What I really need to get to know is how to represent knowledge and facts.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mention that it can't be based on certain language/libraries. Do you have a specific implementation environment in mind?

Comment: He obviously wants to write it directly in machine code.  Seriously, I guess that he actually means "language-agnostic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get any of the good texts on AI, there will be a section on expert systems; you can, if forced, work it out from there and implement your own.

The basic idea is really fairly simple: you have a collection of rules in "if-then" form that represent inferences, or4 implications.  Like, for example:

```
IF blood temperature > 41°C 
THEN patient.has-fever := TRUE

IF patient has wet-sounding breathing
THEN patient.has-pneumonia

IF patient.has-fever AND patient.has-pneumonia
THEN CONCLUDE bacterial pneumonia. ACTION prescribe Augmentin
```

In other words, you have a bunch of rules, and you evaluate the rules until you get to a conclusion.  There's a lot more to is (forward or backward chaing and that kind of thing) which you can read about in thed pretty decent [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) article.

I'm puzzled why you can't use an existing rule engine though -- there are a number of them, for most languages, usually under pretty liberal licenses.  That's really an easier route unless this is a homework problem or something.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is well suited to writing rule-based systems (a pretty standard approach to expert systems development). P# compiles to C#, which may meet your needs - and it's free.

[More information](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PrologNET.aspx) on P#.

Answer (score 0):

The basis rationale, and mathematical proof, for the [PROLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) language, should help you understand most of the concepts you will need to address, if not provide the final language you need to use to implement it.

I couldn't find a link to the original implementation, but it would not help you much anyway. Alain Colmerauer's early work on logic programming should be helpfull.

[EDIT] Sorry, duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for some implementation of Prolog or CLIPS, depending if backward or forward chaining logic best suits the problem. Instead of re-implementing either of these, spend the time working out how to integrate them with your environment.

Answer (score -1):

Jess is a good choice but you should read the book "Jess in action" as a first step.